# how to use useMemo with injectIntl

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const  PrintList = memo(({list})=>{
  console.log("render");
  return "List ...";
});


function HelloWorld({ intl, ...props }) {
  const list = useMemo(() => ["key1", "key2"].map((id) => intl.formatMessage({ id }) 
  )
  , [intl]);

  return <PrintList list={list} />;
}

const HelloWorldContainer= injectIntl(HelloWorld);
```

How can I memoize the rendered output of PrintList when the list prop depends on intl?

Comment: You can do it the way you did it, it looks ok. What is the problem with your current code?